# Drop --temporary-- indexes in Mysql/Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to recover a semi corrupted InnoDB table. I noticed the issue while trying to add a new index to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE `<table>` ADD INDEX `<name>`
ERROR 1712 (HY000): Index "TEST008"--temporary-- is corrupted
```

The `check table <table> EXTENDED` doesn't pick up on the issue.

```
+---------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table         | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+---------------+-------+----------+----------+
| <table>       | check | status   | OK       |
+---------------+-------+----------+----------+
```

I have tried to drop the corrupted index using
ALTER TABLE table DROP INDEX `"TEST008"--temporary--\` but it ends up with

```
ERROR 1091 (42000): Can't DROP '"TEST008"--temporary--'; check that column/key exists
```

Am I forced to recreate the table using for example `OPTIMIZE`?

Comment: What ENGINE does the table use?

Comment: @RickJames The table is using InnoDB.

Comment: copy the data to a new table, and bzuild your indexes or try the classics https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.htmlu

Comment: First time I read about a corrupted index using the *InnoDB* engine (which usually gives satisfaction). Maybe you should also check your disk / memory.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @[nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk), if you can't get rid of a corrupted index you'll need to reconstruct the table. Do you make occasional back ups? In example I literally stop the database service and copy the entire database directory including the MariaDB binary and everything. Redundancy seems like overkill until you need it.

The most basic way to accomplish reconstructing the table is by using the following:

```
INSERT INTO `table_new` SELECT * FROM `table_old`;
```

There are some threads floating around the web about how to do that faster though this one I could test without errors in MariaDB. Just rename the old table in case you find a better approach *after* you reconstruct the table. I recently updated some database tables I created a decade ago after I was given bad advice from someone over naming conventions and now I can greatly expand the functionality of that software now if needed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should check the indexes status which will not show under `CHECK TABLE`.

To do that, try the following

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'userstat';
SET GLOBAL USERSTAT = ON;
-- just to get all columns used from the stats table
-- SHOW COLUMNS FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`INDEX_STATISTICS`

-- get all indices just in case
SELECT * FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`INDEX_STATISTICS`;

-- get all indices for the table
SELECT * FROM  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`INDEX_STATISTICS` WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'yourTable';
```

That will clear out what is indexed and what is not in your tables.

Another thing is that when you add/drop indices better use ticks like `\`TEST008`` rather than `"TEST008"`. If this neither works... clone/copy the table content, drop it and re-create it.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `backupTable`
  SELECT * FROM `yourTable`;
```

For additional information please read [Create Temporary table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#create-temporary-table)

Make sure that this will happen as this memory table could fail due to the size of the index size. If that happens you should increase or change HASH indexing algorithm in use.

If everything works as expected **ADD** the temp table lines on the next statement

> **Note**: make sure to add all those missing fields

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `yourTable`;
CREATE TABLE `yourTable`(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- other columns
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) Engine=InnoDB; -- or extend this with collation, and other instructions

INSERT INTO `yourTable`
  SELECT * FROM `backup`;
```

This should do the trick.

Last case solution is to hard remove from file system the InnoDB table but I doubt that this is the case.